# Which one is appropriate: "I am taking a recurring training" or "I am taking a recurrent training"

Tags: word-choice, difference, adjectives

I am emailing my supervisor and I want to let her now that I am taking a training that happens every week at the same time (like a series of trainings).

Comment: You are on a weekly training course. You are having a training session every Thursday afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say neither.  The training is the set of classes.  The classes recur; the training doesn't.

You could say "I'm taking a recurring set of classes", or "I'm in a training course that involves a weekly set of classes".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are having "regular" training. You could also say "weekly training"

Recurring isn't quite the right word. If the training recurs, it sounds like you are being trained on the same thing.  Recurrent training similarly suggests "the same event happening over and over."  A recurrent dream is when you have the same dream repeatedly.